# Optimizing big Lucene index fails silently

Tags: lucene

I have a question on optimizing big Lucene index (it's 197 Gb now - may sound not that big for some of you).
I'm using Lucene of version 2.9.4 and I came to a state when I need to optimize an index with 900 segments into much smaller number of segments (1-10 ideally). I'm still calling IndexWriter.optimize() that's available in 2.9.4, but setting merge factor fails the same way.

So, what happens is that after an hour of optimizing my logs (I have set up all possible logs) say that optimization is done and no errors are there in any logs file. Everything looks fine except the fact that the files in index directory are still the same - no number of files reduced or deletes expunged.
I have enough space on drive (300 Gb) and no readers or searchers are open - the index is isolated and focused on optimization.

According to index wirter logs the merge threads merge segments and print out some numbers of segments from 900 down to 456 iteratively and then suddenly it says that it's merging all of them up to 16 segments (that's the number or segments that I set to merge to)

Does anyone have any idea what could happen? Am I merging too many segments? Could there be any OS related (Windows Server 2008) issues like 'Too Many File Handlers Open' (where can I check that message)?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible to go to lucene 4 ? (maybe 3 as a stop gap) there are a lot of bug fixes you might want

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but we're quite dependent on Lucene 2.4 API (with those deprecated Hits and so on). I resolved the issue, actually. I tried to start with indexing few more documents first, then commit them and run optimization only after that in the same thread. That solved the issue. I can only accume that the index was in some inconsistent state and few more writes/commits to index made  it work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a failure. The issue is very simple - you just need to open index reader (or re-open existing one) after optimization got completed. That's it. It will replace old index files with list of new files right when you open the reader in few seconds.